# Why does next(some_generator_func()) yield a different result from next(a_var), where a_var = some_generator_fun()?

Tags: python

Let some_generator_func() be the function:

```
def some_generator_fun():
    yield 1
    yield 2
```

Why is it that

```
>>>>next(some_generator_func())
1
>>>>next(some_generator_func())
1
```

whereas

```
>>>>a_var = some_generator_func()
>>>>next(a_var)
1
>>>>next(a_var)
2
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first case, you create a *new* generator expression each time you call the function. This means you will create a brand new generator, then call `next` which will effectively call the first element each time.

When you assign it to a variable, you are yielding elements from that generator each time you call `next`.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `some_generator_func` creates a new iterator starting from the top of the function. Therefore, in the first case, you iterate two fresh iterators; in the latter case, you iterate the same iterator twice.